# Why is the main chat room frozen?

Tags: support, chat

I was going to post a message in the site's [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) but it's not visible by default in the [list of DIY chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com).  When I click on the *Show Frozen/Deleted Rooms* button and join the room, I get the message:

> This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.

Is this a glitch on the chat server?  Or perhaps an oops by the staff or moderators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, there doesn't seem to have been a particularly active room to talk about previously. We *do* try to keep at least one room open per site, but it *looks* like some 1:1 rooms (question-related rooms between a few users) were taking precedence. I've changed it such that after the next build those 1:1 rooms will be excluded when considering room pruning (when it asks: "is there a more appropriate room to forcibly keep alive for this site?")